# Open a file from SD card in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to Open my file called `apps.xml` and let other apps handle the file. How do I do that? I have tried this but it does nothing at all. No force closes

```
File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Download");
File gpxfile = new File(root, "list.xml");
```

and in `manifest` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: it SAYS "The method startActivity(Intent) in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments ()" when I trY to add

Comment: Please add all relevant code for context and understanding

Comment: Try to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31991285/android-reading-from-file-on-sd-card/31994360#31994360

Answer (score 0):

you might have to request runtime permission to access the file,

```
public void requestPermissionForExternalStorage() {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "External Storage permission needed. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
```